# How to change Shape width in layer-list?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want a background around my `TextView` with only bottom border. For that I am using layer-list.But my problem is how to change size of the border.

Here is my layer-list

```
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/category_border"/>
    <item
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/category_bg"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

This is my category_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:thickness="0.1dp">

    <solid android:color="#d5d5d5" />

</shape>
```

And this is my category_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```